# convert very big exponential to decimal in c#

Tags: c#, int, exponential

5.35754303593134E+300 to 53575430359313400000000000000000000 ... 000000000

Can anyone do this because this number is very large?

I have tried:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            double s = double.Parse((System.Math.Pow(2, 999)).ToString(), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Float);
            Console.WriteLine("value={0}", s);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you would need a string type.

Comment: For future reference, you don't need to add `<br/>` tags in code, just indent it all by four spaces and the built-in formatting will detect it as code.

Comment: Its not working. it gives---   Value was either too large or too small for a Decimal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do one of the following,

```
Console.WriteLine(s.ToString("N0")); //comma separated
Console.WriteLine(s.ToString("F0"));
```

Both works.

Comment: Welcome. Maybe, you want to mark the answer as well, as your question is answered.

Answer (score 0):

Your title and your code says different things but..

Basicly, you *can't*. [`decimal`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75.aspx) can't hold this value because it is way outside of it's range. It's range from 7.9 x 10<sup>28</sup> to 7.9 x 10<sup>28</sup>.

You can save it on double (which `Math.Pow` return type and you don't *even* need to get it string representation and parse it to double again in such a case) or [`BigInteger`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.aspx).

```
double s = Math.Pow(2, 999);
```

or

```
BigInteger s = (BigInteger)Math.Pow(2, 999);
```

If you wanna get this value it's string representation, you can use ["`E`" standard numeric format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#EFormatString) like;

```
s.ToString("E14") // 5,35754303593134E+300
```

Or you can use Jon Skeet's [`DoubleConverter` class](http://jonskeet.uk/csharp/DoubleConverter.cs) which exact representation of it's value;

```
DoubleConverter.ToExactString(s) // 5357543035931336604742125245300009052807024058527668037218751941851755255624680612465991894078479290637973364587765734125935726428461570217992288787349287401967283887412115492710537302531185570938977091076523237491790970633699383779582771973038531457285598238843271083830214915826312193418602834034688
```

Comment: @amitpradhan Added as an example with it's value and it's string representations part.